# Object ID of a Python integer variable larger than 256

Tags: python, loops, object, variables, integer

I used this code to observe the id of `int` objects. we know that after 256, python creating different object for `int` variables. But my code says that python use same object for variable even the value is greater than 256. Why this is happening?

```
for n in range(0,500):
    a = n
    b = n
    id_a = id(a)
    id_b = id(b)
    print(n, a is b, id_a, id_b)
    if not a is b: break
```

Comment: There is only *one* integer object created on each iteration, and then assigned the names ``n``, ``a`` and ``b``. There is nothing in the code *requiring* Python to change that.

Comment: yes, I changed my code as ```a = int(str(n))```, ```b = int(str(n))```, then it worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = n
b = n
id(b) == id(a)
# True
```

Does not create new objects, but references to the same object. You would have to enforce new `int` objects, e.g. in this case where you don't have literals:

```
a = n + 1 - 1
b = n + 1 - 1
id(b) == id(a)
# False  # for n > 256  
# True   # for n <= 256
```